# Why Apple send me message saying my app did not support Ipv6?

Tags: ios, app-store, afnetworking, ipv6

My application is rejected with the follow information:

> 发件人 Apple
>   1. 5 SAFETY: DEVELOPER INFORMATION
>   2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
>   Safety - 1.5
>
> The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/, does not properly navigate to the intended destination.
>
> Specifically, your support URL displayed “This site can’t be reached” error message.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app’s support URL to ensure it directs users to a webpage with support information.
>
> Performance - 2.1
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 10.2.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, your app displayed a connection error when logging in with the provided demo accounts.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.
>
> Resources
>
> For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking.
>   With the two follow images:

http://a1198.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple122/v4/60/8b/eb/608bebae-1c3b-cc93-2a01-9f512965f622/attachment-3951093649653869315Screenshot-0217-073348.png?downloadKey3=1487836993_30f3e33d7be2d3ba3c3e89d7e3393952

http://a1225.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple111/v4/58/78/7a/58787a76-b8a2-8016-e5fe-412c7fcaf8dc/attachment-8366771332257964417Screenshot-0217-073415.png?downloadKey3=1487836993_592f44ae84cf1f391301263be58175b6

1.First, I do not understand the issue `1.5`.

2.Secondly, my application is use AFNetworking 3.1.0, and in a swift-oc mixture project.

[image]
[image]

My network Util is this, one of the method is list:

```
#import "Mysevers.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "HUD.h"

@implementation Mysevers

+(void)AFPOSTWithHud:(BOOL)hud andAddressname:(NSString*)addressName parmas:(NSDictionary*)parmas RequestSuccess:(void(^)(id result))success failBlcok:(void(^)(void))failBlcok
{
    if (hud) {
        [HUD addHUD];
    }
    AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,addressName];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);


    [requestManager POST:urlStr parameters:parmas progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        if (hud) {
            [HUD removeHUD];
        }
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            if (hud) {
                [HUD removeHUD];
            }
            failBlcok();
        }

        return ;
    }];

}
```

---

**Attention**

My `BASE_URL` is:

### #define BASE_URL @"https://hxsq.luminginfo.cn:8043/app/"

**Additional -1**

I have tested my local ipv6 condition, and it can login.

The DNS is ipv6's.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And my app can login too, so I feel uncertain, my application is support ipv6! but apple send me ipv6 issue, the only doubtful point is my url([hxsq.luminginfo.cn](http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn)) in app can not visit in foreign, such as USA.

Answer (score 2):

It says that your *support URL* is not supported over IPv6.  Therefore, it may not actually be related to your in-app networking code.  I just tried to load that URL in my browser and it also failed.  *You have to have a working support URL.*

If you confirm that it is a problem with your in-app networking, you should check out [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49979#147579) by `Eskimo` who is an engineer at apple.  Specifically, you should test against an IPv6 network, which you can setup using [these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/46545#136166).  If you've gone through the checklist and verified that IPv6 works for you locally, you should respond to app review and ask them to try it again.  We had the same problem a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: `I just tried to load that URL in my browser and it also failed.` this  sentence means what? means under your ipv6 condition test fail?

Comment: When I try to load http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/ in my computer's web browser it gives an "unknown host" error.  You need to have a valid website for your support URL.  This is probably the reason for your rejection.

Comment: @aircraft In particular, the URL must be accessible outside China, and I think your web site is not accessible outside China. It appears to have no DNS records when queried from the USA, for instance.

Comment: @arsenius, but how about the ipv6 issue? I use AFNetworking 3.1.0 in my app, my app is swift + oc mixture project.

Comment: @lme Apple *always* tests on an IPv6 network.  Then, if there is any network trouble they include a comment about IPv6.  It's very unlikely AFNetworking has a problem with IPv6.  I'm using it in a mixed project as well with no issues.

Comment: @arsenius, hi, friend, are you here? can you check this link if can access :   hxsq.luminginfo.cn  ?

Comment: @aircraft No, I still can't reach it due to DNS: `Unknown Host`.

Comment: @arsenius , and then?

Comment: I couldn't reach it before, but I can reach what looks like a login screen now. It's very slow to load, however.

Comment: That address seems to be available now although it is indeed very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Safety - 1.5: In my opinion, at least the support URL (http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/) should navigate the user to download your application. Your URL is just a login page and they may see "Can not access this site" error message when reviewing your app.

Performance - 2.1: You should test your app in IPv6-Only. The official website: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

You can just read the part "Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly".

Comment: the URL(http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/)) must have the path to navigate to download the application?

Comment: NO. It is generally the product introduction page, and attached to the download address or two-dimensional code. You can try to show the image of the app that you provided to Apple when you submit the app. 
In other words it is a product of your home page, if you have a similar product description of the page, you can directly use.

Comment: the official statement : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Comment: Zhange, no , I don't think means that, it means they can not reach the site in US, maybe caused by GFW.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem before,  through my tests, there may fulfill three conditions:
1. App must support https and runs in Ipv6.
2. The BaseUrl shouldn't be ip url(like "122.223.1.1"), it must be public domain name.
3. App need use legal https certificate.

Comment: what mean of `App need use legal https certificate.` ?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found our web-server is not available in USA, but available in China, and I tested ipv6 in my network, it is supported ipv6.

But I send my server page to USA friend they say it is not available in USA, so my server is not available in USA.

So, it is a wrong information from Apple audit team.
They may default verify our app in Ipv6 network, regardless of the server network if is available.

---

My issue is caused by:

I use qcloud, (which is Tencent subordinate cloud server).
At first our backend java colleague only set the second record, point at Inland network, the Foreign can not access our server.Then I add the first record, point at Foreign, so in USA can access the server now.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Then I send my application to Itunes Connect to review, it success.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the solution. The main problem is Cocoapods is setting the "Deployment Target" of Pod Project to "IOS 7.0". so this makes "AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m" class to use old "ipv4" code instad of the new ipv6 block because the "if statement" falls into the wrong side.

the "__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED" statement return "7000" because cocoapods deployment target is set as "7.0" instead of useing the same deployment target as the main project.

```
+ (instancetype)manager
{
    NSLog(@"min iphoneos: %i - %i",__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED,__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED);
#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 90000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 101100)
    struct sockaddr_in6 address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin6_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    NSLog(@"IPV6 Block");
#else
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    NSLog(@"IPV4 Block");
#endif
    return [self managerForAddress:&address];
}
```